# Is there a function to trigger elements when i enter value in input?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to figure it is there a function to trigger a button when i add value on input? Like i have buttons and they are not visible i want to make trigger that buttons when user inputs the exect value of button id or button text doesnt matter.

I will describe it more below

I have too many buttons and they are adding balance to system and i dont want to user sees all of it and they have text and id's like (from 1 to 100). I want to make them clicked when user inputs that value.

I tried to improve that function but i cant.

```
<div>
      <a class="balance"
        href="checkout.js">
        Add 1$ Balance
      </a>
          </div>
      has more 99 button like this.
```

```
<form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
      
      <div id="container">
        <button onclick="text()" id="button">Add that amoun of balance.</button>
        <h1 class="output"></h1>
      </div>
```

```
const input = document.querySelector("input");
        const output = document.querySelector(".output");
        
        function text() {
          output.textContent = input.value;
        };
```

Comment: Why do you want to trigger an invisible button? Why not just call the process the button is meant to call when clicked direct from the input handler?

Comment: There is `onChange` event for inputs, no need for invisible buttons

Comment: @Andy is there any documentation to do it easier way? i am new at this :/

Comment: @jsnewbie Are you just trying to maintain a total amount of the values entered into an input element, and display it somewhere?

Comment: @Andy No, each of the buttons adds a balance of certain value of crypto payment and each of the buttons has a different special link. So, I want the button corresponding to the value entered in the input to be clicked. So, when the user enters a value in the input, my hidden button needs to be clicked. The reason i am doing it is i dont know the API system so i decided to do a temporary solution.

Comment: [You may want to use a object/dictionary for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) with the value as the key, and the corresponding value as the link. And then you can access that by `obj[value]`.